# Converting crystal report expressions to vb code

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I'm new to crystal reports and .net technologies. I have recently started working on them and I want to know whether the crystal report expressions can be converted to an equivalent vb code, so I can use them in SSRS reports.

Also the below crystal report expressions by itself looks like sort of vb code(someone correct me if I am wrong).

**Crystal report formula:**

```
local StringVar x :="";

if not isnull({Availability.Address}) and trim  {Availability.Address}) <> "" 
and {Availability.Address} <> {Availability.Building} 
then x := x + {Availability.Address} + chr(10);

if not isnull({Availability.Park}) and trim({Availability.Park}) <> "" 
then x := x + {Availability.Park} + chr(10);

if not isnull({Availability.City}) and trim({Availability.City})
<> "" then if not isnull({Availability.State}) 
then x := x + {Availability.City} + ", "
else  x := x + {Availability.City} + " ";

if not isnull({Availability.State}) and trim({Availability.State})    
<> "" then x := x + {Availability.State} + " ";

if not isnull({Availability.Zip}) and trim({Availability.Zip})   
<> "" then     x := x + {Availability.Zip} + " ";
x;
```

**VB Code:**

```
Public Function Test(ByVal profit As String) As String
{
    //crystal report expressions as vb code?
}
```

Now can I convert this crystal formula into vb code?

**Note:** `Availability in the formula is the stored procedure name and followed by a field name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function formula(ByVal address_1 As String, _
                ByVal building_name_formatted_rpt As String, _
                ByVal park_name As String, _
                ByVal city As String, _
                ByVal state As String, _
                ByVal zip As String) As String

    Dim x As String = ""

    If Not IsDBNull(address_1) And Trim(address_1) <> "" And address_1 <> building_name_formatted_rpt Then
        x = x & address_1 & Chr(10)
    End If


    If Not IsDBNull(park_name) And Trim(park_name) <> "" Then
        x = x & park_name & Chr(10)
    End If

    If Not IsDBNull(city) And Trim(city) <> "" Then
        If Not IsDBNull(state) Then
            x = x & city & ", "
        Else
            x = x & city & " "
        End If
    End If


    If Not IsDBNull(state) And Trim(state) <> "" Then
        x = x & state & " "
    End If


    If Not IsDBNull(zip) And Trim(zip) <> "" Then
        x = x & zip & " "
    End If

    Return x
End Function
```

Comment: I get this error. `Function 'formula' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used`.